# Apache Commons Email setup (cannot be resolved to a type), I appear to have correct JARs

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to get this code for sending a basic email, which I found on the Apache Commons Email User Guide, working:

```
package reporting;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class Email {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(465);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setFrom("ross.donohoe@tvgmedia.com");
        email.setSubject("TestMail");
        email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
        email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
        email.send();
    }
}
```

An similar question exists on this forum, but the answer advises to download a JAR which I already have. I have the following JARs in my build path:
- activation-1.1.1.jar
- javax.mail-1.6.2.jar
- commons-email-1.5.jar
- commons-email-1.5-javadoc.jar
- commons-email-1.5-sources.jar
- commons-email-1.5-test-sources.jar
- commons-email-1.5-tests.jar
- mail-1.4.jar

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a naming conflict with your class and a class you need to import. Your class is called `Email` so it will conflict with the `org.apache.commons.mail.Email` you need to import, so rename your class to something else (both the class definition and the file name) and you should be golden.

Alternatively you can change your code to refer to the Commons Email class with the fully qualified name, but I'd just rename your class unless you really must call it `Email` and can't rename it.

```
org.apache.commons.mail.Email email = new SimpleEmail();
```

Apart from that, check that you have these imports and it should work:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
```

Comment: I've added those imports, but still getting the same issue. The line "import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;" is underlined in red with comment "The import [...] conflicts with a type defined in the same file"... I've triple checked the jars are in my build path.

Comment: @r-donohoe Aaah, that might be it. Can you paste your full .java file content, it sounds a lot like you have a naming conflict.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the full .java file contents

Comment: Updated my answer, you have a naming conflict with your class name. Rename your class (your IDE can do that for you with no hassle) and it should remove the obstacle.

Comment: Ahh amazing thank you. The import is now working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your imports were done properly. If they are, then maybe your IDE is having issues reaching the file imported in your .m2 folder.

You can go to your user directory,open .m2 folder, look for that file, delete it and reimport it, or just restart your IDE.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry then, I thought it's a maven project.

Comment: I have set up a Maven project to attempt to solve this issue, same problem. I have found the .m2 folder, which file am I looking for to delete? I have deleted and reimported commons.email-1.5.jar, but that didn't fix the issue